# Android get data from cursor when click on layout?

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I have a layout for my list row with some text and a layout which is supposed to emulate a button. The problem I'm facing is I will always get the latest data in the cursor, meaning if I click the layout on row one I should get grp id 1 and grp name ONE, but I'm getting grp id 3, grp name THREE regardless of which layout I click on in the listview. What's the way to fix this? My code:

In the getView method

```
ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text2 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            holder.layout1 = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.info);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        String grpCount = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(TestDbAdapter.KEY_GRP_COUNT));

        holder.text2.setText("Channels: " + grpCount);

        holder.layout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TestDbAdapter.KEY_GRP_NAME)));
                System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TestDbAdapter.KEY_GRP_ID)));
            }
        });

        return vi;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check it, I think it should get fix like this:

```
 String grpCount = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(TestDbAdapter.KEY_GRP_COUNT));
final String grpName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TestDbAdapter.KEY_GRP_NAME));
final String grpId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TestDbAdapter.KEY_GRP_ID));

        holder.text2.setText("Channels: " + grpCount);

        holder.layout1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println(grpName);
                System.out.println(grpId);
            }
        });
```